# Pixel Interpolation in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, interpolation

I imported my character to my game in Unity. I sliced the sprites and made an animation, as usual. When I'm placing the character and play the game, some white dots are appear on the character. During the animation these white dots blinking on the character, making it noisy.  I attached an image, maybe you can see, what I'm talking about (sorry for the wrong resolution).

I would like to kindly ask your help, what could be the problem here. My designer said, he used the same method to exporting sprites than an another character. The another character works fine. 
My designer said, it's all because of pixel interpolation.

[image]

Comment: hey @fafase , thank you for answering, I'll get back you late afternoon today (UK time)

Comment: Thanks, it was the Mip Maps. add you comment as answer , so I can accept it. Can you please explain in your answer what does it mean to check or uncheck the mip map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they NPOT? Can't say if that is the reason, but Unity works better in most cases when the image is power of two. Do you have mip-maps enabled?

Comment: mip-maps was enabled. I distracted it, what solved my problem !
Thank you very much